# How to get the number of rows in a resultset using medoo

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

I would like to know how to get the number of rows in a resultset for this statement:

```
$data=$db->query("SELECT name FROM users")->fetchAll();
```

I need something similar to `mysqli_num_rows` but using `medoo`.

thanks for your help!

Comment: If `count` is not an option, because of the specific query you are running, you would need to provide us with that specific query instead - otherwise, the answers below will be flooded with answers that aren't applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `query()` method returns an array, just use php's [count() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to determine the number of records returned (do not set the recursive mode).

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there is a [count](http://medoo.in/api/count) method:

```
$count = $database->count("users");
```

Comment: Could you put the mentioned complex query (change table names if you want) to get an idea...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
[Counts](http://medoo.in/api/count) the number of rows:

```
$count = $database->count($table, $where);
```